# How to read data from firestore database without trigger functions in index.js file?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have stored some data in firestore. There is collection(books) which link to document(book id)and book id has field like name, image,location,title.
I have another collection(Users) which has document(user id)user id has field as token id .Whenever there will be any write operation in book collection then I have to send notification to all the user using token id .
I am able to send notification to all user if I have hard-coded token id in my index.js file of firestore.
But I have to send notification dynamically. I am not able to read user id from collection users.

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Books/{book_id}").onWrite((change, context) => {
const book_id = context.params.book_id;

console.log("Book ID: " + book_id);

return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).collection("Notifications").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult => {

      const tokenid= queryResult.data();

     const token_id='fOGd94em4ik:APA91bHyZBGBYvO_ZFlLO1lWL1LU-r-1JkuF3fuKieWvV4HuPDKAiG5hdn-BQrMPFeICBdKZ3UR2nkM2PMxClEzVI3V2C38OxoP-1w71Dz-GbO0sbDlg-nswCMZ';

     const payload = {
            notification : {
                title : 'Hi',
                body : 'New Books list is available in the database! Please check the book store',
                icon : "default"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(result => {
            //console.log("Notification sent");
            return 0;
        });

});
});
```

In above code I want to read user_id from collection users. How can I read it since it is not linked with collection books ,I am not able to read.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well and if token_id is a key in users record, you may try something like this:

```
admin.firestore().collection('Users')
.where('token_id', '==', 'YOUR_TOKEN').get()
.then(snap => snap.docs.map(user => { 
   // iterate on your notification process
})
```

Comment: I want to get all token ids from collection Users. my database structure is Books->book id-> field (name, image,title).  .      another collection is Users->userid->field(token id).   if I will get userid from users then I will be able to get token id ...please give me method to get userid.

Comment: I guess something like this should do the trick, though I must admit I don't get why you would need to do just that.:

`const uids = []; 
admin.firestore().collection('Users').get()
.then(snap => snap.docs.map(user => uids.push(user.id))`